# UICollectionView with pagination showing part of next/previous pages

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create an interface where cards are presented one at a time to the user. The user can scroll left and right in a paged fashion, so whenever the user is not scrolling a full card is visible in the centre of the screen. I also want to view a small amount of the card to the left and the right of the current card, as a hint that there is more to see. Ideally, cards would gradually shrink as the move away from the centre of the screen. A very rough example of this would be:

[image]

I'm assuming this can be done with a custom flow layout, but I really have no idea where to start. Something like this is essentially what I'm looking for, but I'd much prefer to use a collection view: https://github.com/kejinlu/PagedFlowView

Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?